# How do I find out which section group, the current section group is in the sidebar in Onenote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2016

When I'm using OneNote I notice that sometimes instead of searching for something in the sidebar on the left, I'm working in a section, and I want to know in the sidebar on the left where that section is...is there a way to easily find out where the current section is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is, put fewer items in a section group.  Only the items in the section group from which the current selection and that way when you click an item within the parent section group, you'll be able to see which section group it is in.